# Computing the volume of the union of axis-aligned cubes

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science

Given is a set `S` of `n` axis-aligned cubes. The task is to find the volume of the **union** of all cubes in `S`. This means that every volume-overlap of 2 or more cubes is only counted once. The set specifically contains all the coordinates of all the cubes.

I have found several papers regarding the subject, presenting algorithms to complete the task. [This paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82116384.pdf) for example generalizes the problem to any dimension `d` rather than the trivial `d=3`, and to boxes rather than cubes. This paper as well as a few others solve the problem in time `O(n^1.5)` or slightly better. Another paper which looks promising and is specific to `3d-cubes` is [this one](https://users.cs.duke.edu/%7Epankaj/publications/papers/vol-cube.pdf) which solves the task in `O(n^4/3 log n)`. But the papers seem rather complex, at least for me, and I cannot follow them clearly.

Is there any relatively simple pseudocode or procedure that I can follow to implement this idea? I am looking for a set of instructions, what exactly to do with the cubes. Any implementation will be also excellent. And `O(n^2)` or even `O(n^3)` are fine.

---

Currently, my approach was to compute the total volume, i.e the sum of all volumes of all the cubes, and then compute the overlap of every 2 cubes, and reduce it from the total volume. The problem is that every such overlap may (or may not) be of a different pair of cubes, meaning an overlap can be for example shared by 5 cubes. In this approach the overlap will be counted 10 times rather just once. So I was thinking maybe an inclusion-exclusion principle may prove itself useful, but I don't know exactly how it may be implemented specifically. Computing every overlap (naively) is already `O(n^2)`, but doable. Is there any better way to compute all such overlaps?
Anyways, I don't assume this is a useful approach, to continue along these lines.

Comment: I'd use a plane-sweep / line-sweep approach. The plane sweep converts the problem from overlapping 3D cubes into a series of problems with overlapping 2D squares. The line sweep converts an overlapping squares problem into a series of problems with overlapping 1D line segments. The overlapping line segment problem is trivial to solve.

Comment: fwiw, a naive implementation of the sweep algorithm runs in `O( n^3 * logn )` worst case. That's not quite as good as what you were hoping for, but the actual running time only approaches that limit when every cube overlaps every other cube.

Comment: @user3386109 The plane-sweep approach is what the authors of some papers mention. But implementing it is what I find hard. Can you outline the steps of the procedure? perhaps a pseudocode?

Comment: Looks like David Eisenstat has done better than pseudocode, and provided a full python solution. I haven't studied it thoroughly, but based on past contributions from David, I expect it's top notch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented Bentley's algorithm (O(n^2 log n)) in C++. (I know you wanted Java, but C++ is my main ax at work, and templates are just too useful here given that I was considering working my way up to Overmars and Yap.)

```cpp
// Import some basic stuff from the standard library.
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <memory>
#include <optional>
#include <random>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

// Define vocabulary types.

class Interval {
 public:
  Interval(double a, double b) : min_(std::fmin(a, b)), max_(std::fmax(a, b)) {}

  double min() const { return min_; }
  double max() const { return max_; }

 private:
  double min_, max_;
};

// Cartesian product of an interval and a set.
template <typename Projection>
class IntervalTimes {
 public:
  IntervalTimes(Interval interval, Projection projection)
      : interval_(interval), projection_(projection) {}

  Interval interval() const { return interval_; }
  Projection projection() const { return projection_; }

 private:
  Interval interval_;
  Projection projection_;
};

// Zero-dimensional base case.
struct Interval0 {};

using Interval1 = IntervalTimes<Interval0>;
using Interval2 = IntervalTimes<Interval1>;
using Interval3 = IntervalTimes<Interval2>;

using Box = Interval3;
Box MakeBox(Interval x, Interval y, Interval z) {
  return IntervalTimes{x, IntervalTimes{y, IntervalTimes{z, Interval0{}}}};
}

// Define basic operations.

double Length(Interval interval) { return interval.max() - interval.min(); }

double Measure(Interval0) { return 1; }

template <typename Projection>
double Measure(IntervalTimes<Projection> product) {
  return Length(product.interval()) * Measure(product.projection());
}

bool Contains(Interval interval, double x) {
  return interval.min() < x && x < interval.max();
}

bool Contains(Interval i1, Interval i2) {
  return i1.min() <= i2.min() && i2.max() <= i1.max();
}

bool Contains(Box box, double x, double y, double z) {
  return Contains(box.interval(), x) &&
         Contains(box.projection().interval(), y) &&
         Contains(box.projection().projection().interval(), z);
}

bool Intersects(Interval i1, Interval i2) {
  return std::fmax(i1.min(), i2.min()) < std::fmin(i1.max(), i2.max());
}

template <typename Projection>
std::vector<Projection> ProjectEach(
    const std::vector<IntervalTimes<Projection>>& objects) {
  std::vector<Projection> projections;
  projections.reserve(objects.size());
  for (const IntervalTimes<Projection>& object : objects) {
    projections.push_back(object.projection());
  }
  return projections;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> Select(const std::vector<bool>& included,
                      const std::vector<T>& objects) {
  std::vector<T> selected;
  for (std::size_t j = 0; j < included.size() && j < objects.size(); j++) {
    if (included[j]) selected.push_back(objects[j]);
  }
  return selected;
}

// Returns the unique x values that appear in objects, sorted.
template <typename Projection>
std::vector<double> Boundaries(
    const std::vector<IntervalTimes<Projection>>& objects) {
  std::vector<double> boundaries;
  boundaries.reserve(objects.size() * 2);
  for (const IntervalTimes<Projection>& object : objects) {
    boundaries.push_back(object.interval().min());
    boundaries.push_back(object.interval().max());
  }
  std::sort(boundaries.begin(), boundaries.end());
  boundaries.erase(std::unique(boundaries.begin(), boundaries.end()),
                   boundaries.end());
  return boundaries;
}

// The basic offline algorithm for d dimensions uses the online algorithm for
// d-1 dimensions. Each object gives rise to two events. We sweep over the
// events, integrating as we go using the online algorithm.

template <typename Object>
class OnlineMeasure {
 public:
  virtual ~OnlineMeasure() = default;

  virtual void Initialize(std::vector<Object>) {}

  // Adds the object at index j in the objects presented to Initialize().
  virtual void Add(std::size_t j) = 0;

  // Removes the object at index j in the objects presented to Initialize().
  virtual void Remove(std::size_t j) = 0;

  // Returns the measure of the union of the objects added but not removed.
  virtual double Measure() const = 0;
};

enum class Side { kMin, kMax };
// {x, side, index}.
using Event = std::tuple<double, Side, std::size_t>;

template <typename Projection>
double OfflineMeasure(const std::vector<IntervalTimes<Projection>>& objects,
                      OnlineMeasure<Projection>& online_measure) {
  // Construct the events and sort them by x with min before max.
  std::vector<Event> events;
  events.reserve(objects.size() * 2);
  for (std::size_t j = 0; j < objects.size(); j++) {
    Interval interval = objects[j].interval();
    events.push_back({interval.min(), Side::kMin, j});
    events.push_back({interval.max(), Side::kMax, j});
  }
  std::sort(events.begin(), events.end());

  // Sweep x to integrate.
  double measure = 0;
  std::optional<double> previous_x;
  online_measure.Initialize(ProjectEach(objects));
  for (const auto& [x, side, j] : events) {
    if (previous_x) measure += (x - *previous_x) * online_measure.Measure();
    previous_x = x;
    switch (side) {
      case Side::kMin:
        online_measure.Add(j);
        break;
      case Side::kMax:
        online_measure.Remove(j);
        break;
    }
  }
  return measure;
}

// We can use the algorithm above as a slow online algorithm.
template <typename Projection>
class OfflineOnlineMeasure : public OnlineMeasure<IntervalTimes<Projection>> {
 public:
  OfflineOnlineMeasure(
      std::unique_ptr<OnlineMeasure<Projection>> online_measure)
      : online_measure_(std::move(online_measure)) {}

  void Initialize(std::vector<IntervalTimes<Projection>> objects) override {
    objects_ = std::move(objects);
    included_.assign(objects_.size(), false);
  }

  void Add(std::size_t j) override { included_.at(j) = true; }

  void Remove(std::size_t j) override { included_.at(j) = false; }

  double Measure() const override {
    return OfflineMeasure(Select(included_, objects_), *online_measure_);
  }

 private:
  std::unique_ptr<OnlineMeasure<Projection>> online_measure_;
  std::vector<bool> included_;
  std::vector<IntervalTimes<Projection>> objects_;
};

// Zero-dimensional base case for Klee's algorithm.
class KleeOnlineMeasure : public OnlineMeasure<Interval0> {
 public:
  void Add(std::size_t) override { multiplicity_++; }
  void Remove(std::size_t) override { multiplicity_--; }
  double Measure() const override { return multiplicity_ > 0 ? 1 : 0; }

 private:
  std::size_t multiplicity_ = 0;
};

double KleeMeasure(const std::vector<Box>& boxes) {
  std::unique_ptr<OnlineMeasure<Interval0>> measure0 =
      std::make_unique<KleeOnlineMeasure>();
  std::unique_ptr<OnlineMeasure<Interval1>> measure1 =
      std::make_unique<OfflineOnlineMeasure<Interval0>>(std::move(measure0));
  OfflineOnlineMeasure<Interval1> measure2(std::move(measure1));
  return OfflineMeasure(boxes, measure2);
}

// The fundamental insight into Bentley's algorithm is a segment tree that
// solves the online problem in one dimension.
class Segment {
 public:
  explicit Segment(Interval interval)
      : left_{nullptr},
        right_{nullptr},
        interval_{interval},
        multiplicity_{0},
        descendant_length_{0} {}

  Segment(std::unique_ptr<Segment> left, std::unique_ptr<Segment> right)
      : left_{std::move(left)},
        right_{std::move(right)},
        interval_{left_->interval_.min(), right_->interval_.max()},
        multiplicity_{0},
        descendant_length_{left_->LengthOfUnion() + right_->LengthOfUnion()} {
    assert(left_->interval_.max() == right_->interval_.min());
  }

  double LengthOfUnion() const {
    return multiplicity_ > 0 ? Length(interval_) : descendant_length_;
  }

  void Add(const Interval i) { Increment(i, 1); }
  void Remove(const Interval i) { Increment(i, -1); }

 private:
  void Increment(const Interval i, std::size_t delta) {
    if (Contains(i, interval_)) {
      multiplicity_ += delta;
    } else if (Intersects(i, interval_)) {
      left_->Increment(i, delta);
      right_->Increment(i, delta);
      descendant_length_ = left_->LengthOfUnion() + right_->LengthOfUnion();
    }
  }

  // Children.
  std::unique_ptr<Segment> left_;
  std::unique_ptr<Segment> right_;
  // Interval.
  Interval interval_;
  // Adds minus removes for this whole segment.
  std::size_t multiplicity_;
  // Total length from proper descendants.
  double descendant_length_;
};

std::unique_ptr<Segment> ConstructSegmentTree(
    const std::vector<double>& boundaries) {
  if (boundaries.empty()) return nullptr;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Segment>> segments;
  segments.reserve(boundaries.size() - 1);
  for (std::size_t j = 1; j < boundaries.size(); j++) {
    segments.push_back(
        std::make_unique<Segment>(Interval{boundaries[j - 1], boundaries[j]}));
  }
  while (segments.size() > 1) {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Segment>> parent_segments;
    parent_segments.reserve(segments.size() / 2 + segments.size() % 2);
    for (std::size_t j = 1; j < segments.size(); j += 2) {
      parent_segments.push_back(std::make_unique<Segment>(
          std::move(segments[j - 1]), std::move(segments[j])));
    }
    if (segments.size() % 2 == 1) {
      parent_segments.push_back(std::move(segments.back()));
    }
    segments = std::move(parent_segments);
  }
  return std::move(segments.front());
}

class BentleyOnlineMeasure : public OnlineMeasure<Interval1> {
 public:
  void Initialize(std::vector<Interval1> intervals) override {
    intervals_ = std::move(intervals);
    root_ = ConstructSegmentTree(Boundaries(intervals_));
  }

  void Add(std::size_t j) override { root_->Add(intervals_.at(j).interval()); }

  void Remove(std::size_t j) override {
    root_->Remove(intervals_.at(j).interval());
  }

  double Measure() const override {
    return root_ != nullptr ? root_->LengthOfUnion() : 0;
  }

 private:
  std::vector<Interval1> intervals_;
  std::unique_ptr<Segment> root_;
};

double BentleyMeasure(const std::vector<Box>& boxes) {
  std::unique_ptr<OnlineMeasure<Interval1>> measure1 =
      std::make_unique<BentleyOnlineMeasure>();
  OfflineOnlineMeasure<Interval1> measure2(std::move(measure1));
  return OfflineMeasure(boxes, measure2);
}

int main() {
  std::default_random_engine gen;
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> uniform(0, 1);
  std::vector<Box> boxes;
  static constexpr std::size_t kBoxCount = 20;
  boxes.reserve(kBoxCount);
  for (std::size_t j = 0; j < kBoxCount; j++) {
    boxes.push_back(MakeBox({uniform(gen), uniform(gen)},
                            {uniform(gen), uniform(gen)},
                            {uniform(gen), uniform(gen)}));
  }
  std::cout << KleeMeasure(boxes) << "\n";
  std::cout << BentleyMeasure(boxes) << "\n";

  double hits = 0;
  static constexpr std::size_t kSampleCount = 1000000;
  for (std::size_t j = 0; j < kSampleCount; j++) {
    const double x = uniform(gen);
    const double y = uniform(gen);
    const double z = uniform(gen);
    for (const Box& box : boxes) {
      if (Contains(box, x, y, z)) {
        hits++;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  std::cout << hits / kSampleCount << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Wow, amazing. I am going to see if I can convert this to Java and see how it works, and if it can help me in the project. If you're able to reach Overmars and Yap it would be insanely impressive. I am also going to see if this helps me understand the actual maths behind it and come up with anything that resembles a pseudocode.

Comment: [van Leeuwen and Wood](http://www.cs.uu.nl/research/techreps/repo/CS-1979/1979-06.pdf) review Bentley's algorithm in detail, and it seems like a reasonably accessible writeup as far as research papers go, since it's a tech report that wasn't trying to meet a page limit.

Comment: I will try read it later. Still trying to convert the code to Java. Seems like it's really difficult sadly.

Comment: @MCFromScratch I'll take a crack at it.

Comment: @MCFromScratch https://github.com/eisenstatdavid/KleeMeasureProblem

Comment: @MCFromScratch I think I understand O&Y at this point, and I definitely understand the core idea of measuring trellises quickly, but the implementation seems like it will get messier than I have time for right now.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some Python (sorry, didn't notice the Java tag) implementing user3386109's suggestion. This algorithm is O(n³ log n). We could get down to O(n³) by sorting the events for all cubes once and extracting the sorted sub-sequence that we need each time, but perhaps this is good enough.

```py
import collections

Interval = collections.namedtuple("Interval", ["lower", "upper"])
Cube = collections.namedtuple("Cube", ["x", "y", "z"])


def length(interval):
    return interval.upper - interval.lower


def length_of_union(intervals):
    events = []
    for interval in intervals:
        events.append((interval.lower, 1))
        events.append((interval.upper, -1))
    events.sort()
    previous = None
    overlap = 0
    total = 0
    for x, delta in events:
        if overlap > 0:
            total += x - previous
        previous = x
        overlap += delta
    return total


def all_boundaries(intervals):
    boundaries = set()
    for interval in intervals:
        boundaries.add(interval.lower)
        boundaries.add(interval.upper)
    return sorted(boundaries)


def subdivide_at(interval, boundaries):
    lower = interval.lower
    for x in sorted(boundaries):  # Resort is O(n) due to Timsort.
        if x < lower:
            pass
        elif x < interval.upper:
            yield Interval(lower, x)
            lower = x
        else:
            yield Interval(lower, interval.upper)
            break


def volume_of_union(cubes):
    x_boundaries = all_boundaries(cube.x for cube in cubes)
    y_boundaries = all_boundaries(cube.y for cube in cubes)
    sub_problems = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for cube in cubes:
        for x in subdivide_at(cube.x, x_boundaries):
            for y in subdivide_at(cube.y, y_boundaries):
                sub_problems[(x, y)].append(cube.z)
    return sum(
        length(x) * length(y) * length_of_union(z_intervals)
        for ((x, y), z_intervals) in sub_problems.items()
    )


# Test code below.

import random

Point = collections.namedtuple("Point", ["x", "y", "z"])


def mean(sequence):
    n = 0
    x_bar = 0
    for x in sequence:
        n += 1
        x_bar += (x - x_bar) / n
    return x_bar


def random_interval():
    a = random.random()
    b = random.random()
    return Interval(min(a, b), max(a, b))


def in_interval(x, interval):
    return interval.lower <= x <= interval.upper


test_intervals = [random_interval() for i in range(10)]
sample_coordinates = [random.random() for i in range(1000000)]
sampled_length = mean(
    any(in_interval(x, interval) for interval in test_intervals)
    for x in sample_coordinates
)
print(length_of_union(test_intervals), sampled_length)


def random_cube():
    return Cube(random_interval(), random_interval(), random_interval())


def in_cube(point, cube):
    return (
        in_interval(point.x, cube.x)
        and in_interval(point.y, cube.y)
        and in_interval(point.z, cube.z)
    )


test_cubes = [random_cube() for i in range(10)]
sample_points = [
    Point(random.random(), random.random(), random.random()) for i in range(1000000)
]
sampled_volume = mean(
    any(in_cube(point, cube) for cube in test_cubes) for point in sample_points
)
print(volume_of_union(test_cubes), sampled_volume)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem recursively, by defining an algorithm to solve the problem for D-dimensional cubes (where D=1 are lines, 2 are squares, 3 are cubes, etc.). I assume cubes are a struct with two points (start and end) that define their boundaries.

Note: I didn't run this code, but it should work (up to silly python mistakes). Complexity is expected to be O((N log N)^D) where D is the number of dimensions, and the code should be straight forward.

```py
# Define a recursive computation, working on a given set of cubes and
# an index of the current dimension.
def find_union_area(cubes, dim_index=0):
  if len(cubes) == 0:
    return 0

  # We want to have a list of tuples of the form `(x_val, side, cube)` where
  # side is either start or end.
  starts = [{
    'val': cube.start[dim_index],
    'side': 'start',
    'cube': cube
  } for cube in cubes]
  ends = [{
    'val': cube.start[dim_index],
    'side': 'start',
    'cube': cube
  } for cube in cubes]

  # Sort all start and end locations of the cubes along the current axis.  
  locations = sorted(starts + ends, key=lambda l: l['val'])

  # Iterate the above list, each time on the interval between x_i and x_(i+1)
  # to compute the overall volume/area minus overlap.
  result = 0

  curr = locations[0]
  assert cur['side'] == 'start'

  # Track the cubes in the current interval
  current_cubes = {loc.cube}

  for loc in locations[1:]:
    prev = curr
    curr = loc
 
    if curr['side'] == 'end':
      current_cubes.remove(curr['cube'])
    else:
      current_cubes.add(curr['cube'])

    # If the current interval has 0 length, it is non-interesting
    # This would happen if two cubes start/end at the same place along the axis
    if curr['val'] == prev['val']:
      continue

    # If the current interval is empty it is also non-interesting
    if len(current_cubes) == 0:
      continue
    
    # If we are in 1-D (i.e. this is the last dimension), the size of
    # the interval is simple
    if dim_index == len(curr.cube.start):
      result += curr['val'] - prev['val']
    # Otherwise we need to check the volume also using the next dimensions
    # for the current cubes, and then multiply by that
    else:
      curr_dim_size = curr['val'] - prev['val']
      next_dims_size = find_union_area(current_cubes, dim_index + 1)
      result += curr_dim_size * next_dims_size
 
  return result
```